# XSL : Attribute name from value of random element or other attribute

Tags: attributes, element

I need to send the value of element to the attribute, which overwrite that attribute name. Value of the attribute remain the same.

Example:

```
<engine hybrid="yes">
  <A>2000</A>
  <B>diesel</B>
  <C>160</C>
</engine>
```

What i need to achieve for example:

```
<engine diesel="yes">
  <A>2000</A>
  <B>diesel</B>
  <C>160</C>
</engine>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your input, what is your output, what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should base your transformation on the *identity template*, which copies everything from the input to output unchanged except where this behaviour is overridden by more specific templates

```xml
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

With this in place you can then just add a specific template for the `engine` element

```xml
<xsl:template match="engine">
  <engine>
    <!-- create an attribute whose name is taken from the first B child -->
    <xsl:attribute name="{B}">yes</xsl:attribute>
    <!-- and continue processing child nodes (but not other attributes) -->
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </engine>
</xsl:template>
```

The key thing to note here is that the `name` attribute of `xsl:attribute` is treated as an "attribute value template" - you can enclose parts of the value in braces `{}` and these parts will be evaluated as XPath expressions rather than being taken as literal values.

Finally, of course, you should note that this will only work if the content of `B` is a valid XML attribute name (so no whitespace, no characters like `=` or `"`, and it must not start with a digit).

Comment: Thank You very much, Ive got some issues with the value of the element, but now it works perfectly. Thank You!

Comment: @user3143802 glad it helped, and welcome to Stack Overflow. When you get an answer that solves your problem it's good manners to _accept_ it by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer. As well as rewarding the answerer this shows other people at a glance that the problem is solved.